# java regex to find words in string finds empty strings in symbols like .,!(? and empty space

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my case string:

```
"This is a test.  How many???  " + "Senteeeeeeeeeences are here... there should be 5!  Right?"
```

using 
`String[] words = getText().split("[( +)!.?,]");`

I get this array:
`[This, is, a, test, , , How, many, , , , , Senteeeeeeeeeences, are, here, , , , there, should, be, 5, , , Right`

How can I eleiminate empty strings?

Comment: Use [`String[] words = getText().split("[\\s+()!.?,]+");`](https://regex101.com/r/az9laE/1)

Comment: What is the criteria for splitting? These symbols only or any whitespace/punctuation? Maybe you need `split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")`?

Comment: @MiniBug Do you want just extracting the word? not anything else.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. `Your solution  String[] words = getText().split("[\\s+()!.?,]+");` fits quite nicely.

Comment: Shall I post? I see you accepted another solution.

Comment: Both are correct. :-)

Comment: `\W` matches much more than `[(\s+)!.?,]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> your question is not clear enough.
> If it is **not** as you went tell me, then
> I may **update** the answer or **delete** it.

---

You just need to match **all non-words** globally. that's it.

**what you need**
`[^\w]+`

**how it work**
For splitting, it matches everything except `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

---

### [prove](https://regex101.com/r/EqBnUX/1)

**Fast test**

```
echo "This is a test.  How many???  " + "
 Senteeeeeeeeeences are here... there should 
 be 5!  Right?" | perl -lne 'print "@{[split( /[^\w]+/g )]}"'
```

**output**
`This is a test How many Senteeeeeeeeeences are here there should be 5 Right`

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringToSearch = "This is a test.  How many???  " + "Senteeeeeeeeeences are here... there should be 5!  Right?";

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[\\W]+");
String[] str = p1.split(stringToSearch);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str));
```

output:

[This, is, a, test, How, many, Senteeeeeeeeeences, are, here, there, should, be, 5, Right]